# Excel graph recalculating values

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have this table of water consumption values, with twelve Jan-Dec columns, each flat has one line. But the cells contain value from the meter, so it is not a consumption in the month, but rather complete consumption to the date, ever growing. Now what I need would be a graph of monthly consumption, but with those values I'm obviously getting constantly growing line, while monthly consumption should be presented like a flat line (when there is a constant consumption). I can do a simple help table containing monthly values by substracting columns but I was curious if that could be somehow achieved directly within a graph. Can I put some equation into series definition or something similar?
Left side shows original data and their graph, while right side uses computed values per each month, it makes changes in consumptions very apparent and that's the whole point.
[image]

Comment: Sample data and a visual of your desired result would be helpful. Many folks will not read w/out data and a desired output sample.

Comment: I can't think of a way of doing a chart which shows changes from one point to the next in a series of running totals, just like I can't think of a way of charting a running total directly from a series of separate values (the opposite problem). In both cases a helper table will be the easiest to build and troubleshoot.

Comment: I added some example pic. AdamV, so you say helper table is mandatory? OK, not big deal, I just hoped it will be somehow easier to analyze data in Excel this way, but the helper table is ok I guess.

Comment: @Ren,, you have picked wrong graph,, since you want MONTHLY consumption of  each flat then  better work with BAR graph & for better visualization add TREND LINE for every month,, I'm sure this will solve the issue!!

Comment: In real data I have more than 50 series so bar graph would make it totally useless, it's hardly reasonably arranged with line graphs split by house. But anyway, no, simply changing the shape of the graph wouldn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can I put an equation into a chart series definition or data range?**

The short answer is "yes with limitations". You can use named ranges within the *chart data range* and series definitions, and define the names with formulae in its "refers to" textbox, subject to these limitations:

- Named ranges must be provided with a sheet reference e.g. `=sheet1!data`
- Named ranges that contain formulas e.g. `=Sheet1!$B$3:$B$10-Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9` can only be used in an individual series' name, X or Y data fields.
- Named ranges that are used (with sheet reference) in the *chart data range* textbox will immediately resolve to its source reference (but if defined with formulas it will be ignored)

**How can I calculate the derivative of a graph in Excel?**

Unfortunately Excel doesn't have a one-click "add 1st order derivative" feature for charts - which is exactly what you need to calculate the usage per month from monthly totals. You can use the above named range trick to calculate the differences without helper columns, but you will need one named range for every column / series (defined with a subtraction formula as in the picture below - note, a true derivate needs (y1-y0)/(x1-x0) but your (x1-x0) = 1 month). Then you would need to plot the original data, with all 50? series and manually edit each series, replacing the y data range with its corresponding defined name (and probably reducing the x series data range by one cell, as the named range will have n - 1 rows). This isn't very practical to set up for more than a few series, unless automated via VBA code.

**Simplifying the helper columns/tables**

In theory you can define the whole difference table as a single named range e.g. `=Sheet1!$B$3:$Z$10-Sheet1!$B$2:$Z$9`, but I could not find a reliable way to plot it without helper columns. It does make the helper tables easier to make though. You can use the named range as an array formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER or simply with spilling in Office 365. Alternatively you could define a single name to calculate the difference for a single column directly adjacent to the it, using relative references i.e. `=Sheet1!B3:B10-Sheet1!B2:B9` (defined while in cell C3). Excel automatically adjust the relative references relative to the cell the name is being used in.

[image]

Comment: Now that's something, thank you. While it's clearly much easier to stick with helper table, tip for simplifying the process is appreciated. And +1 for making me realize it's actually 1st order derivative what I'm looking for here, it's been a while since my school days...